# Should methods returning Task<T> always start the returned task?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

If I have a method like

```
Task<bool> LongProcessTaskAsync();
```

Would it be a better practice to return a started task

```
return Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(() => { ... });
```

or just `return new Task<bool>(() => ...)`

Personally, I prefer the first method but I'd rather be consistent will other API's and libraries.

Is returning a not-started task ever more appropriate?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the case of async/await methods, the Task will already be started.  AFAIK, all the BCL methods added for Task-based versions return already-started Tasks.  It would be kinda weird not to, since the common consumer case is now:

```
var foo = await GetFooAsync();
```

[**EDIT**] Based on Stephen pointing out that the TAP guidelines covers this (and he already includes a link to the guidelines), I'll include a quote of the relevant bit from page 4 (in The Task-based Asynchronous Pattern Defined -> Behavior -> Task Status), and I've added bold+italics around the key parts.

> *Task Status*
>
> The Task class provides a life cycle for asynchronous operations, and
>   that cycle is represented by the TaskStatus enumeration.  In order to
>   support corner cases of types deriving from Task and Task as
>   well as the separation of construction from scheduling, the Task class
>   exposes a Start method.  Tasks created by its public constructors are
>   referred to as “cold” tasks, in that they begin their life cycle in
>   the non-scheduled TaskStatus.Created state, and it’s not until Start
>   is called on these instances that they progress to being scheduled. 
>   All other tasks begin their life cycle in a “hot” state, meaning that
>   the asynchronous operations they represent have already been initiated
>   and their TaskStatus is an enumeration value other than Created.
>
> ***All tasks returned from TAP methods must be “hot.”***  If a TAP method
>   internally uses a Task’s constructor to instantiate the task to be
>   returned, the TAP method must call Start on the Task object prior to
>   returning it. ***Consumers of a TAP method may safely assume that the
>   returned task is “hot,” and should not attempt to call Start on any
>   Task returned from a TAP method.***  Calling Start on a “hot” task will
>   result in an InvalidOperationException (this check is handled
>   automatically by the Task class).

Comment: +1. The [Task-Based Asynchronous Pattern guidelines](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957) state the returned `Task` should be started. Any `async` code using your method would expect it to be started, particularly if it follows the TAP naming guidelines (i.e., ending in `Async`).

Comment: Non-started tasks are really only used by Task Parallel Library code. There are other `Task` APIs inherited from TPL that shouldn't be used in TAP code: `Task.Wait`, `Task.WaitAll`, `Task.WaitAny`, `Task.Result` - essentially anything dealing with blocking.

Comment: @StephenCleary suppose I call `var myTask = DoWorkAsync();` (without await) in the first line of some async code, then I call some others as well like `var myOtherTask = DoMoreWorkAsync();`. Then I do some other stuff, now before ending my method I need to be sure these two tasks (which started asynchronously) had finished. I'd either use `Task.Wait(myTask, myOtherTask);` or `await myTask; await myOtherTask;`. You wanted to mean my first option shouldn't be used, and that I should instead use `await` (with `ConfigureAwait(false)`), or did I misunderstood?

Comment: @Alisson: If it's at the end of the method, I'd use `await Task.WhenAll(myTask, myOtherTask).ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Answer (score 3):

James Manning correctly answered. Here is another angle: Why would anyone *want* an unstarted task? If he did, he could have just waited calling the method. He could have called it later, or wrapped it in a Lazy or future himself. There is almost never a reason not to return a started task.

Comment: An unstarted `Task` can be executed in any context. So - in theory - you could use an unstarted `Task` as a unit of work where the execution context doesn't matter (i.e., the `TaskScheduler` is left up to the caller). However, I've never seen anyone do this in practice.

Comment: Ok, never thought of that. Probably it is best to pass in a TaskScheduler to the method called so it can decide if it actually *wants* to be executed on a different TaskScheduler.