# Why does GC collects my object when I have a reference to it?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, async-await

Let's look at the following snippet which shows the problem.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var task = Start();
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Console.WriteLine("Starting GC");
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            Console.WriteLine("GC Done");
        });

        task.Wait();

        Console.Read();
    }

    private static async Task Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start");
        Synchronizer sync = new Synchronizer();
        var task = sync.SynchronizeAsync();
        await task;

        GC.KeepAlive(sync);//Keep alive or any method call doesn't help
        sync.Dispose();//I need it here, But GC eats it :(
    }
}

public class Synchronizer : IDisposable
{
    private TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs;

    public Synchronizer()
    {
        tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>(this);
    }

    ~Synchronizer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("~Synchronizer");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dispose");
    }

    public Task SynchronizeAsync()
    {
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

Output produces:

```
Start
Starting GC
~Synchronizer
GC Done
```

As you can see `sync` gets Gc'd(more specifically finalized, we don't know about memory gets reclaimed or not). But why? Why would GC collect my object when I have a reference to it?

**Research:**
I've spent some time investigating what happens behind the scenes, It seems that state machine generated by the C# compiler is kept as a local variable, and after the first `await` hit, it seems that the state machine itself goes out of scope.

So, `GC.KeepAlive(sync);` and `sync.Dispose();` doesn't help as they live inside the state machine where as state machine itself is not there in scope.

C# compiler shouldn't have generated a code which leaves my `sync` instance to go out of scope when I still need it. Is this a bug in C# compiler? Or am I missing something fundamental?

PS: I'm not looking for a workaround, but rather a explanation of why the compiler does this? I googled, but didn't found any related questions, if it is duplicate sorry for that.

**Update1:** I've modified the `TaskCompletionSource` creation to hold the `Synchronizer` instance, that still doesn't help.

Comment: You don't seem to return anything from `private static async Task Start`.

Comment: @GSerg Why does that matters?

Comment: Because you have `var task = Start();` - what are you assigning?

Comment: That's how `async` works, it will create a `Task` object.

Comment: @GSerg I'm assigning the task returned by `Start`. I'm waiting for it with `task.Wait` later.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen You mean this is the expected behavior? Isn't this against the intuition?

Comment: Not at all, my comment was in answer to @GSerg. Your question is by no means expected behavior, at least *I* didn't expect it.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It confused me that there is a task created inside the method but nothing is returned. In fact a `Task<void>` is returned, but that task is not really related to the task created inside `Start` - it has `method: null`, so the inside `task` is indeed a stray one. If you remove `async` from `Start`'s declaration and `return task` from it, it will look less confusing.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22268569/async-await-custom-awaiter-and-garbage-collector) can shed some light

Comment: Also maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18091002/11683).

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Thanks that helps, but hard to believe and hard requirement to keep the strong reference myself :(

Comment: By the way, I cannot reproduce the issue on the recent .NET Core 3.1 (release mode + running from command line).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What `GC.KeepAlive(sync)` - which is [blank by itself](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/gc.cs,18b31b2edcc0f711) - does here is just an instruction to the compiler to add the `sync` object to the state machine `struct` generated for `Start`. As @usr pointed out, the *outer* task returned by `Start` to its caller does *not* contain a reference to this *inner* state machine.

On the other hand, the `TaskCompletionSource`'s `tcs.Task` task, used internally inside `Start`, does contain such reference (because it holds a reference to the `await` continuation callback and thus the whole state machine; the callback is registered with `tcs.Task` upon `await` inside `Start`, creating a circular reference between `tcs.Task` and the state machine). However, neither `tcs` nor `tcs.Task` is exposed *outside* `Start` (where it could have been strong-referenced), so the state machine's object graph is isolated and gets GC'ed.

You could have avoided the premature GC by creating an explicit strong reference to `tcs`:

```
public Task SynchronizeAsync()
{
    var gch = GCHandle.Alloc(tcs);
    return tcs.Task.ContinueWith(
        t => { gch.Free(); return t; },
        TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously).Unwrap();
}
```

Or, a more readable version using `async`:

```
public async Task SynchronizeAsync()
{
    var gch = GCHandle.Alloc(tcs);
    try
    {
        await tcs.Task;
    }
    finally
    {
        gch.Free();
    }
}
```

To take this research a bit further, consider the following little change, note `Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite)` and the fact that I return and use `sync` as the `Result` for `Task<object>`. It doesn't get any better:

```
    private static async Task<object> Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start");
        Synchronizer sync = new Synchronizer();

        await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite); 

        // OR: await new Task<object>(() => sync);

        // OR: await sync.SynchronizeAsync();

        return sync;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var task = Start();
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Console.WriteLine("Starting GC");
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            Console.WriteLine("GC Done");
        });

        Console.WriteLine(task.Result);

        Console.Read();
    }
```

**IMO, it's quite unexpected and undesirable that `sync` object gets prematurely GC'ed before I could access it via `task.Result`**.

Now, change `Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite)` to `Task.Delay(Int32.MaxValue)` and it all works as expected.

Internally, it comes down to the strong reference on the `await` continuation callback object (the delegate itself) which should be held while the operation resulting in that callback is still pending (in flight). I explained this in "[Async/await, custom awaiter and garbage collector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22268569/async-await-custom-awaiter-and-garbage-collector)".

IMO, the fact that this operation might be never-ending (like `Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite)` or incomplete `TaskCompletionSource`) should not be affecting this behavior. For most of naturally asynchronous operations, such strong reference is indeed held by the underlying .NET code which makes low-level OS calls (like in case with `Task.Delay(Int32.MaxValue)`, which passes the callback to the unmanaged Win32 timer API and holds on to it with `GCHandle.Alloc`).

In case there is no pending unmanaged calls on any level (which might be the case with `Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite)`, `TaskCompletionSource`, a cold `Task`, a custom awaiter), there is no explicit strong references in place, **the state machine's object graph is purely managed and isolated**, so the unexpected GC does happen.

I think this is a small design trade-off in `async/await` infrastructure, to avoid making *normally* redundant strong references inside `ICriticalNotifyCompletion::UnsafeOnCompleted` of standard `TaskAwaiter`.

Anyhow, a possibly universal solution is quite easy to implement, using a custom awaiter (let's call it `StrongAwaiter`):

```
private static async Task<object> Start()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start");
    Synchronizer sync = new Synchronizer();

    await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite).WithStrongAwaiter();

    // OR: await sync.SynchronizeAsync().WithStrongAwaiter();

    return sync;
}
```

`StrongAwaiter` itself (generic and non-generic):

```
public static class TaskExt
{
    // Generic Task<TResult>

    public static StrongAwaiter<TResult> WithStrongAwaiter<TResult>(this Task<TResult> @task)
    {
        return new StrongAwaiter<TResult>(@task);
    }

    public class StrongAwaiter<TResult> :
        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ICriticalNotifyCompletion
    {
        Task<TResult> _task;
        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter<TResult> _awaiter;
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle _gcHandle;

        public StrongAwaiter(Task<TResult> task)
        {
            _task = task;
            _awaiter = _task.GetAwaiter();
        }

        // custom Awaiter methods
        public StrongAwaiter<TResult> GetAwaiter()
        {
            return this;
        }

        public bool IsCompleted
        {
            get { return _task.IsCompleted; }
        }

        public TResult GetResult()
        {
            return _awaiter.GetResult();
        }

        // INotifyCompletion
        public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
        {
            _awaiter.OnCompleted(WrapContinuation(continuation));
        }

        // ICriticalNotifyCompletion
        public void UnsafeOnCompleted(Action continuation)
        {
            _awaiter.UnsafeOnCompleted(WrapContinuation(continuation));
        }

        Action WrapContinuation(Action continuation)
        {
            Action wrapper = () =>
            {
                _gcHandle.Free();
                continuation();
            };

            _gcHandle = System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.Alloc(wrapper);
            return wrapper;
        }
    }

    // Non-generic Task

    public static StrongAwaiter WithStrongAwaiter(this Task @task)
    {
        return new StrongAwaiter(@task);
    }

    public class StrongAwaiter :
        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ICriticalNotifyCompletion
    {
        Task _task;
        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter _awaiter;
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle _gcHandle;

        public StrongAwaiter(Task task)
        {
            _task = task;
            _awaiter = _task.GetAwaiter();
        }

        // custom Awaiter methods
        public StrongAwaiter GetAwaiter()
        {
            return this;
        }

        public bool IsCompleted
        {
            get { return _task.IsCompleted; }
        }

        public void GetResult()
        {
            _awaiter.GetResult();
        }

        // INotifyCompletion
        public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
        {
            _awaiter.OnCompleted(WrapContinuation(continuation));
        }

        // ICriticalNotifyCompletion
        public void UnsafeOnCompleted(Action continuation)
        {
            _awaiter.UnsafeOnCompleted(WrapContinuation(continuation));
        }

        Action WrapContinuation(Action continuation)
        {
            Action wrapper = () =>
            {
                _gcHandle.Free();
                continuation();
            };

            _gcHandle = System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.Alloc(wrapper);
            return wrapper;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Updated**, here is a real-life Win32 interop example illustrating the importance of keeping the `async` state machine alive. The release build will crash if `GCHandle.Alloc(tcs)` and `gch.Free()` lines are commented out. Either `callback` or `tcs` has to be pinned for it to work properly. Alternatively, `await tcs.Task.WithStrongAwaiter()` can be used instead, utilizing the above `StrongAwaiter`.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        static async Task TestAsync()
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

            WaitOrTimerCallbackProc callback = (a, b) =>
                tcs.TrySetResult(true);

            //var gch = GCHandle.Alloc(tcs);
            try
            {
                IntPtr timerHandle;
                if (!CreateTimerQueueTimer(out timerHandle,
                        IntPtr.Zero,
                        callback,
                        IntPtr.Zero, 2000, 0, 0))
                    throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(
                        Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

                await tcs.Task;
            }
            finally
            {
                //gch.Free();

                GC.KeepAlive(callback);
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var task = TestAsync();

            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                Console.WriteLine("Starting GC");
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                Console.WriteLine("GC Done");
            });

            task.Wait();

            Console.WriteLine("completed!");
            Console.Read();
        }

        // p/invoke
        delegate void WaitOrTimerCallbackProc(IntPtr lpParameter, bool TimerOrWaitFired);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool CreateTimerQueueTimer(out IntPtr phNewTimer,
           IntPtr TimerQueue, WaitOrTimerCallbackProc Callback, IntPtr Parameter,
           uint DueTime, uint Period, uint Flags);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a quality of implementation issue here. As always the GC's work is invisible to the code. If there is any way you can observe the state of the object to be finalized it will not be finalized. Except, if you play sneaky tricks with finalizers purely to observe the act of finalization. No reasonable finalizer would be affected by this object graph constellation. This is almost like using the debugger to detect JIT optimizations and then complaining that the JIT modified straight-line code in a detectable way. GC and JIT are not detectable in all reasonable cases. (+1)

Comment: @usr, I respect this design decision of the CLR/C# team, although initially I almost thought it'd be a bug. Yet my concern is about actual interop coding. E.g., a stripped version of something I did run into: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ESRnZk. It will crash if `GCHandle.Alloc(tcs)` and `gch.Free()` lines are commented out, which IMO is quite not obvious. Either `callback` or `tcs` has to be pinned for it to work properly.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed not obvious. I never would have noticed this bug.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer, your linked answer was very helpful. Though it is hard for us to keep the instance alive manually, we have to accept the fact :( Thanks again.

Comment: In your real life example, `callback` is GC'd and timer tries to invoke it, that's where the exception right? I get NRE while running it, but how strange there is no stacktrace ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, right - the callback gets GC'ed and it crashes inside the interop layer, I guess that's why the stack is messed up.

Comment: Whenever you pass a delegate to native code, you have to ensure yourself that the delegate is not GCed as long as the native code can invoke it. This has nothing to do with `Task`s, and `GCHandle.Alloc(tcs)` is not good enough.

Comment: @Svick, fancy seeing you revisiting this. I think we covered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22268569/1768303) and you were a part of the discussion. So I say, ensuring that the delegate is not GC'ed *here* still does have something with the `Task` in this context. Particularly, because it's the task's async state machine (including the ref to the callback it holds) that gets GC'ed here, and `GC.KeepAlive` on the callback doesn't work as expected. Keeping that task alive with `GCHandle.Alloc` keeps the state machine alive, including the callback.

Comment: That said, just doing `GCHandle.Alloc(callback)` would keep the outer state machine alive too, with the same net effect. However, in the OP's question, there is no callback, so doing `GCHandle.Alloc(tcs)` or `GCHandle.Alloc(tcs.Task)` is the way to make it work. Disagree with your neg here.

Comment: @Noseratio Hmm, you're right that `GCHandle.Alloc(tcs)` will work in your case, because of the `GC.KeepAlive(callback)`. But I think it's a confusing way to do it. Rooting `callback` would be simpler and easier to understand. But I still have an issue with your answer: it suggests that `GCHandle.Alloc` is the right solution, even in the absence of PInvoke. And [it's being used as justification for using that](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/19161#issuecomment-408686230) when you don't understand why an awaiter is being GCed in your code.

Comment: @svick I see Toub's point that without `SetResult` this case might be contrived. And I'm not suggesting rooting the `Task` (or its TCS) as an ultimate solution, but what other object would you root, in the context of @SriramSakthivel's original question? His code doesn't have any interop callbacks, it's purely managed. So I only included the interop example to show the analogy with my own linked question, where I do root the callback itself.

Comment: Still, think about this, rooting the callback would not prevent the async state machine from getting GC'ed if the callback itself doesn't reference anything from that state, i.e., any of pseudo-local variables of the `async` method. Do you think that'd be desirable and intuitive?

Answer (score 8):

`sync` is simply not reachable from any GC root. The only reference to `sync` is from the `async` state machine. That state machine is not referenced from anywhere. Somewhat surprisingly [it is not referenced from the `Task` or the underlying `TaskCompletionSource`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091002/what-gotchas-exist-with-tasks-and-garbage-collection)

For that reason `sync`, the state machine and the `TaskCompletionSource` are dead.

Adding a `GC.KeepAlive` does not prevent collection by itself. It only prevents collection if an object reference can actually reach this statement.

If I write

```
void F(Task t) { GC.KeepAlive(t); }
```

Then this does not keep *anything* alive. I actually need to call `F` with something (or it must be possible for it to be called). The mere presence of a `KeepAlive` does nothing.

Comment: `GC.KeepAlive` cannot be inlined, however, which is its sole point for being used, and its sole point for existing in the framework.

Comment: Dispose needs an object reference as it is an instance method. `GC.KeepAlive(sync)` can't be inlined, it is marked with `MethodImpl.NoInlining`

Comment: Where do I say that KeepAlive was inlined? This is not at all in this answer. Dispose is inlined. Calling an instance method on an empty method does not keep the object reference alive. Why would it? The this parameter is simply an unused parameter here.

Comment: I see that you added "because the task you are awaiting never completed". How can the runtime know this for sure that this task will never complete, and thus eliminate any code and thus references that would be used if the task completed. This is the halting problem, there's no way the runtime can know this. So though dispose in this case isn't going to be reached, I fail to see how the runtime can know this for certain.

Comment: No, but he has `GC.KeepAlive(sync)` in his code which should prevent collection. I'm pretty sure there is some strange interaction from the state machine generated by the compiler for the async method in all this. So even though `sync.Dispose` might follow what you said in your answer, `GC.KeepAlive(sync)` won't, so it should still not be collected.

Comment: KeepAlive only keeps an object alive if it is actually reachable. `if(false) KeepAlive(...)` does not keep anything alive.

Comment: Correct, but how can the compiler or JITter know this code isn't reachable?

Comment: Example: `object o = new object(); new Action(() => GC.KeepAlive(o));`. Both objects are dead here despite the call to `KeepAlive`. His code is just a much longer version of this snippet.

Comment: @usr maybe in my example my task never completes, but I have no idea how CLR knows that, but in my original code, however my task will get complete, it is done by holding a `WeakReference` of my synchronizer. So clr can't say that my task will never complete.

Comment: The missing link with that Action example is that this is wrapped up in a task and I'm pretty sure the task is still considered alive.

Comment: The CLR does not know what a task is but it knows that there is no reference to the state machine and to the TCS. Both die. The state machine contained the only reference to `sync`. Where, in your mind, would some piece of code now obtain a new reference from? This object is simply dead.

Comment: Why isn't there a reference to the state machine? `var task = Start();` <-- isn't that the reference?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen good point but the task does not reference the state machine. The chain is: statemachine => TCS => task. A task does not know what a state machine even is.

Comment: If holding on to the task that was returned from calling an `async` method won't keep the tasks and related code alive I'm pretty sure the entire async/await system is useless, which also means I'm pretty sure that is not true.

Comment: Async tasks which are dead can be GC'ed. I have seen that. The thing that prevents this is that there is usually something that initiates completion such as an expiring timer or an IO. This is what holds the root under normal circumstances. Uncompletable TCS'es are collectable. `new TCS()` is clearly collectable. CPU-based tasks are rooted by the scheduler (and if the scheduler drops a task that task indeed goes away).

Comment: And again, how does the runtime know this task is not completable?

Comment: It does not. The task is rooted and stays alive. But the state machine and TCS go away. That deletes the only reference to `sync`. Where, in your mind, is there still a reference? The KeepAlive is a red herring.

Comment: @usr arguing that tasks will not be complete isn't plausible. Did you overlook [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957311/why-does-gc-collects-my-object-when-i-have-a-reference-to-it#comment42454022_26957449)?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I don't see a WeakReference in your code. In any case a WeakReference does not keep anything alive. You might find that the WeakReference is dead and then the task is not completable. But again: The CLR does not know the task is not completable. But the state machine has no roots. Where would there be a root in your mind?

Comment: Ok state machine is out of the scope, alright. But isn't that against the intuition? You claim this is expected behavior? I don't think so. I strongly suspect this is a corner case with c# compiler.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel see my comment above: "Async tasks which are dead can be GC'ed. I have seen that. The thing that prevents this is...". This is normal. Proof: new TCS(). Collectable.

Comment: "Somewhat surprisingly it is not references from the Task or the underlying TaskCompletionSource." <-- I think this is the whole problem. This is what is not expected.

Comment: Well, there is no need to reference it. It is a good thing to allow collection of unused objects. In the code in the question he's playing tricks with finalization and relying on undocumented behavior. I'm not convinced any of those objects *should* be kept alive here.

Comment: @usr check the updated question. I keep the instance of synchronizer in TCS, and thus `Task` will have it in `AsyncState` property. Still no dice.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel the TCS is dead as well. It can't keep anything alive. You could experiment with creating a strong reference using GCHandle to various objects to see how it affects things.

Comment: @usr TCS may be dead, but what about Task returned by TCS? It keeps the `sync` in its `AsyncState` property. Task isn't collectible isn't it, I'm awaiting over it?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel await uses ContinueWith to queue the delegate that the compiler generated. The chain would be: statemachine => sync => tcs => sync. Also: tcs => tcs.Task => continuation => statemachine. But that whole jungle of references in unreachable. Nothing points into this cluster.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, for what is worth the halting problem doesn't say a compiler can never decide on *any* program. It says that no compiler can decide on *every* program. For many programs or fragments, it's quite possible for a compiler to figure it out, and quite a few compilers do make optimizations  based on that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and being patience with the wall of comments. +1 For you. I accepted @Noseratio's answer as his answer here and linked answer was very useful for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You think that you are still reference to Synchronizer, because you assume that your TaskCompletionSource is still reference to the Synchronizer and your TaskCompletionSource is still "alive" (referenced by GC roots). One of these assumption is not right.

Now, forget about your `TaskCompletionSource`

replace the line

```
return tcs.Task;
```

by for example

```
return Task.Run(() => { while (true) { } });
```

then you won't enter the Destructor ever again.

The conclusion is that:
If you want to make sure that a object won't be garbage collected, then you will have to explicitly make a strong reference to it. Don't assume that a object is "safe" because it is referenced by something not in your control.