# What happens to Tasks that are never completed? Are they properly disposed?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

Say I have the following class:

```
class SomeClass
{
    private TaskCompletionSource<string> _someTask;

    public Task<string> WaitForThing()
    {
        _someTask = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        return _someTask.Task;
    }

    //Other code which calls _someTask.SetResult(..);
}
```

Then elsewhere, I call

```
//Some code..
await someClassInstance.WaitForThing();
//Some more code
```

The `//Some more code` won't be called until `_someTask.SetResult(..)` is called.  The calling-context is waiting around in memory somewhere.

However, let's say `SetResult(..)` is never called, and `someClassInstance` stops being referenced and is garbage collected.  Does this create a memory leak?  Or does .Net auto-magically know the calling-context needs to be disposed?

Comment: A TCS is an isolated object. When it is unreachable it gets collected. Its Task does not reference the TCS so you can have an uncompletable Task without any corresponding TCS in memory. If that Task is unreferenced as well it is collected, too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Updated**, a good point by @SriramSakthivel, it turns out I've already answered a very similar question:

[Why does GC collects my object when I have a reference to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957311/why-does-gc-collects-my-object-when-i-have-a-reference-to-it)

So I'm marking this one as a community wiki.

> However, let's say SetResult(..) is never called, and
>   someClassInstance stops being referenced and is garbage collected.
>   Does this create a memory leak? Or does .Net auto-magically know the
>   calling-context needs to be disposed?

If by the *calling-context* you mean the compiler-generated state machine object (which represents the state of the `async` method), then yes, it will indeed be finalized.

**Example:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var task = TestSomethingAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to GC");
    Console.ReadLine();
    GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true);
    GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static async Task TestSomethingAsync()
{
    using (var something = new SomeDisposable())
    {
        await something.WaitForThingAsync();
    }
}

class SomeDisposable : IDisposable
{
    readonly TaskCompletionSource<string> _tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

    ~SomeDisposable()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("~SomeDisposable");
    }

    public Task<string> WaitForThingAsync()
    {
        return _tcs.Task;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SomeDisposable.Dispose");
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Press enter to GC

~SomeDisposable
Press enter to exit
```

IMO, this behavior is logical, but it still might be a bit unexpected that `something` gets finalized despite the fact that the `using` scope for it has never ended (and hence its `SomeDisposable.Dispose` has never been called) and that the `Task` returned by `TestSomethingAsync` is still alive and referenced in `Main`.

This could lead to some obscure bugs when coding system-level asynchronous stuff. It's really important to use `GCHandle.Alloc(callback)` on any OS interop callbacks which are not referenced outside `async` methods. Doing `GC.KeepAlive(callback)` alone at the end of the `async` method is not effective. I wrote about this in details here:

[Async/await, custom awaiter and garbage collector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22268569/async-await-custom-awaiter-and-garbage-collector)

**On a side note**, there's another kind of C# state machine: a method with `return yield`. Interestingly, along with `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerator`, it also implements `IDisposable`. Invoking its `Dispose` will unwind any `using` and `finally` statements (even in the case of incomplete enumerable sequence):

```
static IEnumerator SomethingEnumerable()
{
    using (var disposable = new SomeDisposable())
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Step 1");
            yield return null;
            Console.WriteLine("Step 2");
            yield return null;
            Console.WriteLine("Step 3");
            yield return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Finally");
        }
    }
}
// ...
var something = SomethingEnumerable();
something.MoveNext(); // prints "Step 1"
var disposable = (IDisposable)something;
disposable.Dispose(); // prints "Finally", "SomeDisposable.Dispose"
```

Unlike this, with `async` methods there's no direct way of controlling the unwiding of `using` and `finally`.

Comment: How do you know *"the compiler-generated state machine object"* is guaranteed to be disposed when the object is finalized, though?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft, what do you mean under "be disposed" here? The state machine object doesn't implement `IDisposable`. It's just a boxed `struct`, but all of its fields (like `something` above) do get garbage-collected and finalized (note how `~SomeDisposable` gets invoked) - because the struct itself gets GC'ed.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, thanks for your point about a duplicate, I've marked this one as a wiki.

Answer (score 6):

[You should ensure your tasks are always completed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/02/10218999.aspx).

In the usual case, the "Other code which calls SetResult" is registered as a callback somewhere. E.g., if it's using unmanaged overlapped I/O, then that callback method is a GC root. Then that callback explicitly keeps `_someTask` alive, which keeps its `Task` alive, which keeps the delegate for `//Some more code` alive.

If the "Other code which calls SetResult" is *not* (directly or indirectly) registered as a callback, then I don't *think* there will be a leak. Note that this is not a supported use case, so this is not guaranteed. But I did create a memory profiling test using the code in your question and it does not appear to leak.

Comment: So it depends on where the "other code" is?  I'm confused on how to tell which cases will leak... My use-case is that `WaitForThing()` waits for user input from a user on the other end of an IM client *(and is called from the object that represents a "friend")* and returns it.  However, if that user is removed as a friend, that input can never occur - there is no way for me to "complete" it.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: I recommend that you complete the task as canceled (`SetCanceled`) when the user is removed as a friend.